# inherit a class from another file

Tags: powershell

How do you inherit and use a class from another file?

```
PowerShell version:
 $PSVersionTable.PSVersion   

Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
6      2      1
```

I have tried the following:

```
# $PWD and $local:PSScriptRoot

# using module ../base/base.psm1
# using module $PWD/../base/base.psm1

# using module ..\base\base.psm1
# using module $PWD\..\base\base.psm1

using module ..\base\base.psm1

Class MyClass : base {
...
}
```

Error:

```
Unable to find type [base].PowerShell
Ignoring 'TypeNotFound' parse error on type 'base'. Check if the specified type is correct. This can also be due the type not being known at parse time due to types imported by 'using' statements.PSScriptAnalyzer(TypeNotFound)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PS1 files Just put a dot ( .  ) at the beginning of the line:

```
#LOAD DEV RECIPIES (FUNCTIONS) - not in use (yet)
. "$DeploymentScriptsGitPath\recipies\Recipies-PROD.ps1"
```

For PSM modules you need to import them :

```
Import-Module -name c:\work\tools-kit\powershel\modules\sqlserver\ -DisableNameChecking
```

refer to:

```
get-help import-module -full
```

Comment: Thanks, but same thing

Comment: Also tried with full path, and I am on a mac - if that could do something

Comment: @Chris G. can you share the Powershell version you are using ?